# Why does my selected image only display in the UIImageView the first time I load the view and never again if I select it again

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

This is my first question on StackOverFlow so I hope I'm doing all good for now.

To explain my problem as best as possible, here's the 2 concerned views of my MainStoryBoard : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQSCx.jpg

On the first one, a list of places is displayed with multiple infos hidden like GPS coordonates, phone number, description of the place, name of the picture (xxx.jpg/.png).
When the user click on one of the places in the list, the app brings him to the next view where all of these infos are displayed.

-> Everything appears correctly.

But if I go back to the list, and click again on the same place, then the picture won't display anymore, the UIImageView stays empty.
And it's happening with every places. The picture is displayed only once.

As all pictures are stored in the same place, I "construct" the URL I will set for NSURL.

```
NSString *DebutLien = @"http://www.otmval.com/membre/img_activites/miniature/";

self.currentPlace.photo1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",DebutLien,self.currentPlace.photo1];

    // Loading the picture in background

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0),
            ^{
                NSURL * imageURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.currentPlace.photo1];
                NSData * imageData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL1];
                UIImage * image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                    ^{
                        [imageView setImage:(image1)];
                    });
            });

    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

The result is here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNScV.jpg

As you can see on the left, everything is well displayed.
But on the second image, if I re-select the same place from the list, then the picture do not appear and I don't know why yet.

**Good thing to know, the problem is happening even without using dispatch queue.**

I've been searching for a long time but it seems my problem isn't really easy to describe, so I hope I will find answers here.

Thanks in advance for your comments and taking time to help me with this ! :)

Comment: can you verify your code is getting called the second time, just like the first time? Does it get into the dispatch_async blocks?

Comment: That's because when you add breakpoints you add them "for that thread". When it gets to dispatch_async, that part is executed by another thread. You need to put the breakpoints `inside` the dispatch_async to see it get called(from the new thread)

Comment: I am inclined to think the error is not in the code you posted. Its somewhere else. If you have a project on github or something, post it on here.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.

So the second time, it goes in the first dispatch_async, but not in the second one, the main_queue.

So the picture isn't displayed.

Comment: Do not delete your comments. They might be useful for someone else!

Comment: So do you have an idea why it isn't going in the main_queue ?


I'm afraid I'm not allowed to post this project on github because i'm working on it during my intership.

Comment: run the first dispatch_async in the main thread. remove the inner dispatch_async. Check to see if it works. `Note:`this is not a solution. Its a bad idea. Use it only to figure out error in code.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want me to put all four lines (NSURL, NSData, UIImage and the setImage) in the dispatch_get_main_queue() ? (with the inner dispatch removed)

Comment: yes. Does that work? It will block the main thread. If this doesn't work, the error in your code is elsewhere.

Comment: Same issue, it works the first time and then it doesn't display the picture anymore for the same place selected.

If it's somewhere else, I really don't know where to look at..

Comment: Could it be because the picture was loaded once so it's stocked somewhere, and then if I want to display the picture again the app knows it has already been displayed once and can't reload from the same URL something it already has ?


Because the problem is happening even without using dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

your problem maybe in calling the async block. You can try sync on the inner dyspatch block.

Here you can find detailed explanation why:
[dispatch_sync inside a dispatch_async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002912/dispatch-sync-inside-a-dispatch-async)

I don't have enough reputation, so i will post it as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having the same issue even If I load the picture directly and not in background. The second time the picture won't appear.

Comment: (I tried with dispatch_sync on the inner dispatch block, same issue)

Comment: maybe your variable currentPlace.photo1 is somehow released after the first click, or is empty? have you checked that?

Comment: doing a dispatch_sync onto the main queue is very very risky and should ONLY be done if you are 100% sure the main thread is not busy.

Comment: I checked, even the second time I want to display the picture the link to it is good.

For a reason I don't know yet, the code doesn't go in the main_queue the second time so the picture isn't displayed.